# How convert datetime-local to datetime in Python?

Tags: python

How convert datetime-local (html form type) to datetime in Python?
My html code is:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="istart">
```

When I receive the POST request the istart value comes in a string.

From Post Request I receive that: `u'2015-01-02T00:00'` and I want to parse it to Datetime for insert in database (via sqlalchemy).

Comment: Can you give us an example of a string you'd want to convert?

Comment: I updated the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse your input string by breaking it into a sequence of values, converting the values to integers, and then feeding that sequence into `datetime.datetime()`.

In long form:

```
date_in = u'2015-01-02T00:00' # replace this string with whatever method or function collects your data
date_processing = date_in.replace('T', '-').replace(':', '-').split('-')
date_processing = [int(v) for v in date_processing]
date_out = datetime.datetime(*date_processing)

>>> date_out
... datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2, 0, 0)
>>> str(date_out)
... '2015-01-02 00:00:00'
```

...or as a [substantially less readable] singleton:

```
date_in = u'2015-01-02T00:00' 
date_out = datetime.datetime(*[int(v) for v in date_in.replace('T', '-').replace(':', '-').split('-')])
```

*Note:* There may be more efficient ways of processing this, using `regex` or somesuch. `datetime` may have a native interpreter that I don't know about, as well.

Comment: While this certainly works, the [approach from Alex G](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59993613/5763431) is far more  readable and probably faster and should be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('2015-01-02T00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.. well done, Alex!